# Where to put a period when you quote a title at the end of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, periods

Which one is correct?:

1. I have never heard of "Oranges".

or

2. I have never heard of "Oranges."

Comment: Probably a duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if "Oranges" is the title of a book or something, the second is correct.

If you're just saying you haven't heard of the fruit, you could leave out the quotes.  However, you could also put them in to emphasize that you don't know the word at all -- like, "Is this really a word?"  In which case, you would write:

```
I have never heard of "oranges."
```

See http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp

Answer (score 0):

The second is correct. However, if it is the title of a book or movie, you should italicize it rather than put it in quotations:

> I have never heard of *Oranges*.

This of course makes the whole question of where to put the period moot:)